# find the actual file name of the zip

Tags: shell

I have a file with extension zip. but I don't know which file is exist under the zip file. I want to print the name of the file which is under the zip file.

Note : one zip file contain only one file.

Example: Suppose I have a file with name 123.zip when I unzip this file then unzip file name is 678.txt. So I want to print the name of unzip file which 678.txt on the screen.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the contents of a zip file using

```
unzip -l "name of file.zip"
```